# DBF в MySQL на PHP без доп. конвертиций и библиотек

Tags: php, mysql

добрый день господа

есть в инете много решений конвертации DBF -> MySQL. часть из них на C, часть DBF -> CSV  -> MySQL, есть код который глючит, есть код который рассчитан на малюсинькие DBF'ки, и при конвертации больших файлов -> превышено ожидание, есть решения в стиле мьсье, с доп. библиотеками... и т.п.

подскажите пожалуйста цикл, считывающий поочередно строки из DBF, и записывающий в MySQL. без доп. библиотек, на PHP (или JS). не важно быстрый или медленный, главное что бы работал.

```
// подключаем test_1001.dbf
// начинаем с первой строки
// назначаем переменные по кол-ву столбцов, и заносим в MySQL
// прыгаем на строчку ниже, до окончания файла
```

p.s. очень не хотелось бы оспаривать предпочтение, чем лучше конвертировать DBF -> MySQL, в моем случае охота узнать решение на PHP (или JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На оффсайте описан набор [функций для работы с DBF](http://ua.php.net/manual/ru/ref.dbase.php). Там-же есть и примеры как их использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Не приходилось сталкиваться со структурой данных .dbf, но есть масса программ конвертирующих такие файлы в .csv! Для подачи данных из csv файла в MySQL нужен маленький скрипт!

При условии что разделители в csv будут "**,**"(зяпятые) или "**;**"(точки с запятой)

```
$csv = file('file.csv'); //указываем файл
$sep = ';'; //устанавливаем разделитель
//пляшим
foreach($csv as $k => $v)
{
    $v = preg_split('/'.$sep.'/', $v);
    echo current($v) . next($v) . '<br />'; //тут выполнить запрос к базе!

    //current($v) самое первое значение, для каждной последующей ячейки в таблице     просто продалжать присваивать next($v)
}
```

Для понятия принцыпа основы работы, более чем достаточно!

Comment: описал выше, что такое не катит. тема кстати CSV -> MySql была. интересует именно DBF -> MySQL ( в крайнем случае DBF -> CSV ) , но не программой, а PHP код на странице ( или JS )